# difference between RPG copybook and program

Tags: rpgle, copybook

Could you give me some idea as to looking at file how can I differentiate between RPG copybook and program?

For example, in c, if you have main in the file, you know that it can be used as program.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Simplest, possibly even "quickest", is to try to compile it. Biggest problem would be that you'd need to test as many as four compiles -- as a *PGM, a *MODULE, a SQL *PGM and a SQL *MODULE. If one fails, try the next. Hmmm... I guess also OPM and ILE. Compile with something like OPTION(*NOSRCSTMT *NOXREF *NOGEN) perhaps, and in QTEMP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's an interesting question...it is usually pretty obvious.

I suppose the quick answer is that copy books won't contain different types of specifications.  An RPG IV program can have H, F, D, I, C, O, and P specifications , or their free-form equivalents.  (The specification type is determined by the letter in column 6 of fixed format source).  The order is important and you can't intermix the types.  If you're looking at source that has only one type of specifications, it's probably designed as a copybook.  Since the executable code is contained in C (Calculation) and/or P (Procedure) specs, a source without any C or P specs is a copybook.  While it's usually bad practice to have C or P Specs in a copybook, RPG does allow it and I've seen it done.  But again, the only thing in the copy book would be C or P specs.

**EDIT** <s>You could have a copybook with for instance F & D specs, but the only place it could be included is at the end of a program's F specs prior to any D specs.</s>  You could have a copybook that makes use of compiler directives `/IF DEFINED` to control what part of the copybook is included where.

**EDIT2** Turns out IBM added the ability to intermix F & D specs in version 7.1 and higher.  A source member with just F & D specs would be a copybook So the short answer becomes, a source member with both definition (H, F, D, I, O) specs and executable (C & P) specs is designed to be compiled.

The longer answer, an RPG program also has a "main".  Originally, the only option was what's known now as "cycle-main".  IE. the "main" procedure is the implicitly generated ["cycle"](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAE4W_7.1.0/com.ibm.etools.iseries.langref.doc/c092508683.htm) code that is built into RPG programs.

Then along came RPG IV and ILE.  IBM added a control specification keyword, `NOMAIN`.

```
H NOMAIN
  //or in freeform
  ctl-opt nomain;
```

This resulted in a non-executable module without a "main" procedure; the code normally generated by the compiler for the "cycle" is left out. The resulting *MODULE object would need to be bound into a *PGM object with another *MODULE that provide a main procedure.

Or it could be bound with zero or more other *MODULE objects into a *SRVPGM object; *SRVPGM are just collections of procedures.  Think of them like Windows DLLs.

Then IBM added the option of having a "linear-main" RPG IV program.

```
H MAIN(MYMAIN)
  // or freeform
  ctl-opt main(MYMAIN);
```

Thus the main procedure is whichever procedure you designate.  The generated "cycle" code is again left out of the executable.

So the existence of either the `NOMAIN` or `MAIN` keywords would indicate that a source member is designed to be compiled; assuming there's more too the source.  It's possible there's a "standard options" include file that would include one of those.

The lack of those two keywords would indicate you're dealing with either a cycle main or an include file.

If it's a cycle main program and it takes parameters as input, you'll be able to see the entry parameter list

```
  //Fixed format, old school RPG III, IV
C     *ENTRY        PLIST                                       
C                   PARM                    LCMPNO            2 
C                   PARM                    LNTACT            1

 // fixed format, RPG IV using a "Procedure Interface (PI) to replace *ENTRY PLIST
D CheckDate       PI               
D  lDateIs                       4a

  // free format RPG IV
dcl-pi CheckDate;
  lDateIs   char(4);
end-pi;
```

Note that a key difference in the source between a "cycle-main" program that uses the PI instead of `*ENTRY PLIST` and a linear main is that a linear main procedure is surrounded by an explicit procedure definition.

```
  // linear main
h main(CHECKDATE)
p CheckDate       b
d CheckDate       PI               
d  lDateIs                       4a
  //do something
  *INLR = *ON
  return;
p CheckDate       e

   //cycle main with PI
d  lDateIs                       4a
  //do something
  *INLR = *ON
  return;
```

Comment: @user1578026, I added an edit to cover some special cases where the short answer may not be quite right.

Comment: You might want to note @Barbra Morris answer as well which is really a comment to this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Starting in 7.1 (with the free-form PTFs from 2013), you can mix F and D specs (even in fixed form code).

Comment: Missed that tidbit in the enhancements.  I'll add it to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

rpg copy book is pretty close to    `imports`   in  modern programing languages

Answer (score 0):

A copy book should be used more like a header file in C or C++. Unfortunately it will not have that helpful .h extender to keep things separate. Shop standards can be helpful here. You can keep copybooks in a separate source file or even name them with a specific prefix or suffix to indicate that it is a copybook. I have seen suffixes like _ or _h used on copybooks where the base name is the same as the source member that it is acting as a header file for. Or in the case that copybooks and program source are stored in different source files, a program and it's header file would have the same name.

Like C, RPG4 can have source files that can be compiled into programs and source files that can be compiled into modules (a module is an IBM i term, much like a the unlinked .obj file generated by a C compiler on other platforms) or programs which are fully linked executables. In order for an RPG source to be compiled to a fully linked executable it needs a main procedure. Charles explained the main and nomain keywords for h specs. If the program source doesn't have the nomain keyword, it can be generated as a fully linked program. Be careful though, even though it isn't common, the h specs can be somewhere else, like in their own copybook, or in a dataarea.

Comment: You could use a source member type of RPGLEINC, or a suffix of .rpgleinc if using IFS. The RDI editor supports both RPGLE and RPGLEINC as ILE RPG.